# Can HAR models also be applied on non-volatility data?

Tags: model, autoregressive, heterogeneity

Currently, I am trying to forecast several cash flows of accounts receivable and payable of a company. I want to apply the HAR model due to the simple structure of the model; it incorporates the short-term effects of the data by adding the daily and average weekly and monthly effects to the model. Furthermore, since several products are underlying the cash flow data, it could also be the case that the cash flows for the different products have different volatilities, referring to the Heterogenous Market Hypothesis. Therefore, I was wondering whether you could also apply the HAR model on data different from (realized) volatility.

However, in literature and on the internet, I can only find applications of this model on volatility. Therefore, I was curious whether this model can also be used outside of this application or that you have to transform the data in order to apply the HAR model to the data. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think a HAR model can be applied to time series other than realized volatility. It corresponds to a restricted autoregression*, and the restriction can be helpful if it reduces the model's variance more than it increases its (squared) bias.

*The lower frequency autoregressive components could be expressed as sums of high-frequency autoregressive components, and then every component in the sum effectively shares the same slope coefficient in the model.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and that sounds indeed logical! I was still wondering, do you think that I should transform the data before applying the HAR model? Such as, should the data be stationary before applying the model? Or is that not necessary?

Comment: @Nadine, if the original time series has a unit root, I think HAR could be problematic. Taking first differences might be a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Or I was thinking of adding a trend variable, since you can also add exogenous variables to the HAR model. However, I am not sure whether this would give the same results.

Comment: @Nadine, If the time series has a deterministic trend, you could do that. But if it has a stochastic trend, too (a unit root), I would go with differencing.

Comment: @Nadine, what do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).